# Is this number divisible by $11$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is  $73864589999999923243431$ divisible by $11$? Show and justify?

Usually I would take modulo 11, but it doesnt seem like a reasonable option here. I dont want the answer, just a hint?

Comment: You can ignore those eight nines, at least. :)

Comment: Use the criterion of divisibility by $11$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Numbers are divisible by $11$ whenever the sum of the digits in odd positions differs from the sum of the digits in even positions by a multiple of $11$ (including zero and negative multiples of $11$).

Comment: (+1) ... since $10^k\equiv (-1)^k\pmod{11}$.

Comment: I would think this is a bit too much to give away to someone who wants _just a hint_, and not the full solution minus a few small details.

Comment: How less than this is it possible to give a hint *after the OP said he tried what he did*? This is just fine, imo. +1

Comment: @Arthur: Hmm, it's possible.  It's also possible that this is more or less what the OP wants.  Unfortunately, I've already let the cat out of the bag, so to speak.

Comment: True. But I was contemplating how to hint at the "every other digit" without actually saying it outright, and you took that away from me. \*Sulking in a corner\* Maybe something like Jack's comment above would've been vaguer. I dunno.

Comment: @Arthur: Sorry about that! :-o

Comment: Well, for a hint... Let $x = \sum b_i*10^i$ so $11x = \sum b_i*10^{i+1} + \sum b_i*10^i = b_n*10^{n+1} + \sum( b_{i+1}+b_i)10^i + b_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: $1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13$.

Comment: This is the source of a reasonable divisibility hack for $7$.

Comment: Indeed! And for $13$ too. And it involves about the same amount of work as the well-known test for divisibility by $11$ to get the problem down to $3$ digits.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1 (mouseover to show):

> $10^k \equiv (-1)^k \pmod{11}$

Hint 2 (mouseover to show):

> $$ 73864589999999923243431 =  (1\times10^0) + (3\times 10^1) + (4\times 10^2) + (3\times 10^3) + (4\times 10^4) \\  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + (2\times 10^5 \ldots) + (3\times 10^{21}) + (7\times 10^{22})$$

Hint 3 (mouseover to show):

> Apply Hint 1 to the sequence in Hint 2. What must the summation satisfy under mod 11 to be divisible by 11?

Answer (score -1):

Well. Hint 1: $73864589999999923243431$ is divisible by $11$ if and only if

$73864589999999923243431 - 11= 73864589999999923243420$ is divisible by $11$.

And $73864589999999923243420$ is divisible by $11$ if and only if $73864589999999923243420 - 220 = 73864589999999923243200$ is divisible by $11$ and so on....

Hint 2:  $11*abcdefg = a(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+e)(e+f)(f+g)g$ almost sort of...

So $hijklmnop/11 = h(h-i)(i-j)(j-k)(k-l)(l-m)(m-n)(n-o)(o-p)p$ almost sort of, kind of, not really but in a way it can be almost, not really....

Hint 3:  If $11*abcdefg = a(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+e)(e+f)(f+g)g$ then $a + (b+c) + (d+e) + (f+ g) = (a+b) + (c+d)+(e+f) + g$.  (Actually that is always true....)

Comment: Hint 4:  10 isn't divisible by 11.  a*10 is divisible by 11 iff and only if .... what?

Comment: Hint 5:  $100c + 10b + a \mod 11 \equiv 99c + c + 11b - b +a \mod 11 \equiv c - b + a \mod 11$.